# Cannot define paths in Lua

Tags: lua

I have this directories

project/src/main.lua
project/assets/font.ttf

And I want to define the path to `font.ttf` in `main.lua` so I can load it.

I've tried defining `FONT_PATH = '../assets/font.ttf'` and many variations but they don't work

Comment: Generally I would expect an program to interpret paths relative to the working directory, which I can't tell from your question. (Maybe check with `os.execute("pwd")` if you aren't sure.) For a native executable it is probably the directory of the executable file; for running a Lua script via the stand-alone Lua interpreter, it is the folder that is probably the folder that is open in the shell when you execute it. (Neither of these is necessarily project/src.) If you are using a library to load your font, it may have its own convention, though.

Comment: Is the question about Roblox?

Answer (score 0):

You can always add other paths to the package paths as:

```
local path1 = ';'..'d:/LuaProjects/'..'?.lua'
local path2 = ';'..'d:/LuaProjects/'..'?/?.lua'
package.path = package.path .. path1 .. path2
```

Use the `print (package.path)` for other examples.

But normally the project structure must have main.lua in the root of project:

- project/

  - main.lua
  - fonts/

    - font.ttf

and now you are need to define it as:

```
customFont = love.graphics.newFont("fonts/font.ttf", 24)
```